# Task.WhenAll and task starting behaviour

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I've got a fairly simple application using Task.WhenAll. The issue I am facing so far is that I don't know if I should start the subtasks myself or let WhenAll start them as appropriate.

The examples online show using tasks from framework methods, where it's not clear to me if the tasks returned have already started or not. However I've created my own tasks with an Action, so it's a detail that I have to address.

When I'm using Task.WhenAll, should I start the constituent tasks directly, or should I let Task.WhenAll handle it for fun, profit, and improved execution speed?

For further fun, the subtasks contain lots of blocking I/O.

Comment: Please post some code to illustrate how you are building your tasks. `Task.WhenAll` doesn't start tasks. The general pattern is that methods that return a `Task`, return a _hot_ `Task`. ie. one that is already running. `Task.Run` works like this.

Comment: The point of `Task.WhenAll` isn't to start or control the execution order of tasks. It's to provide an aggregation point; a task that represents the completion of some constituent tasks (and a collection of their results).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`WhenAll` won't start tasks for you. You have to start them yourself.

```
var unstartedTask = new Task(() => {});
await Task.WhenAll(unstartedTask); // this task won't complete until unstartedTask.Start()
```

However, *generally*, tasks created (e.g. using `Task.Run`, `async` methods, etc.) have already been started.  So you generally don't have to take a separate action to start the task.

```
var task = Task.Run(() => {});
await Task.WhenAll(task); // no need for task.Start()
```

Comment: Hey bro. You really explained it well. Kudos

Comment: You can run `task.Start()` on each of the tasks if you use `var task = new Task(() => {  /// code... });` instead of `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 5):

> I've created my own tasks with an Action

When you're working with asynchronous tasks, [the convention is to only deal with tasks already in progress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx). So using the `Task` constructor and `Start` is inappropriate; it would be better to use `Task.Run`.

As others have noted, `Task.WhenAll` only aggregates the tasks; it does not start them for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384(v=vs.110).aspx) will handle the supplied tasks for you, but you can create them using the most common way - by executing Task.Run(Action) or TaskFactory.StartNew(Action) method.

Just for a note: if any of the tasks is completed in **Faulted** state, resulting task will complete in **Faulted** state as well, having [AggregateException](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwig84m7q-fIAhUHng4KHaOUCmo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.aggregateexception(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGtwREXMtXLfG9cgPGw_lGzR2745w&sig2=amrh5aXlfvVpl7QFRifERg) set to its *Exception* property.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this isn't correct. If you provide an unstarted task to `WhenAll`, the resulting task will simply never complete.

Comment: By bad, it depends on the initial state of the task. There are many ways to create a Task, some of those start it automatically.
Thanks, I will update my answer.